# Efficiency at piping functions

Tags: bash, function, pipe, eval

I wrote a function to help piping other functions. But it seriously lacks efficiency.

First I write this function that will wrap others. It reads from the `standard input` and apply the specified `function` to each input:

```
function func_pipe() {
  local func="$1" && shift
  while ifs='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
    $func $line
  done
}
```

I define a pattern for testing purpose:

```
PATTERN="mypattern"
```

I create a 10k lines big file for testing:

```
### Create big file
time for i in $(seq 1 10000); do 
  echo "$i - here I write the pattern $PATTERN for testing purpose."; 
done > bigfile.txt

real    0m38.234s
user    0m10.245s
sys 0m20.050s
```

I write the function that will process my inputs:

```
function process1() {
  echo -e "$@" | egrep "$PATTERN"
}
```

I process the file in search of the pattern. I use the `func_pipe` to deal with `standard input`s. :

```
echo -e "\n[Testing with pipes]"
time cat bigfile.txt \
 | func_pipe process1 \
 | func_pipe process1 \
 | wc -l

real    1m23.898s
user    1m16.992s
sys 1m54.495s
```

Now I will build my command in a string and `evaluate` it later.

First I write a similar function for processing, that will print the piping in a string. Mind the underscore that make the processing functions differ:

```
function _process1() {
  echo " | grep \"\$PATTERN\""
}
```

I define my command and processing strings:

```
cmd="cat bigfile.txt"
cmd_process="$(_process1)$(_process1) | wc -l"
```

I test them:

```
echo -e "\n[Testing with eval]"
time eval "${cmd}${cmd_process}"

real    0m0.014s
user    0m0.015s
sys 0m0.013s
```

It did it in an instant flash. So it seems that piping functions and reading each standard input for each one of them really isn't efficient. At least, I'd like to think that the issue comes from my implementation. My goal is to make them as efficient as piping `unix` commands (`cut`, `sed`, `etc`). I believe those command too read from `stdin`, so I am the one missing some methods. What is missing to improve my wrapping function?

Comment: The 10,000 bigfile.txt loop should take maybe 200 milliseconds. Check that your system and disk aren't otherwise overloaded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a major difference in your two approaches: the second one only spawn one grep process that will read the entire file from stdin, while your first approach will spawn one grep process per input line.

I suspect this to be the cause of the difference you are observing. Spawning a process is cheap but not free.

The first version also occurs more overhead due to the shell (read line by line + passing each line to the subprocess).

Your `func_pipe` should pass the entire standard input to the `process1` function, not try to split it line by line, if you want to reduce this overhead.

Comment: You mean `func_pipe` should pass the entire standard input into the `_process function` right? so the process function should read from stdin, for instance with `cat - | sed ...` instead of being called for each read in the loop. This works better indeed but that was your point correct?

Comment: Also, you can avoid `cat` to shave off some more time (directly use `sed ... -` instead). Search for "useless use of cat" for more details.

Answer (score 1):

Just read in bash is slow, also for each line a new process is forked.

Comment: But how do tools such as grep deal with inputs? They do read each line one after the other right? How is my approach different?